# How does Touchpal show circle on homescreen without "draw over apps" permission?

Tags: permissions, popup

I use the Touchpal keyboard application. For me, this keyboard works best.
Some of you might be familiar with the lucky locker or daily summary crap they keep on showing on this otherwise great app.
I keep seeing this circle that says "WIN" overlayed on my launcher. I think this is the Lucky Locker but I'm not sure.
Force Stopping the Touchpal application removes the circle but it reappears after a short while.

I have disabled Lucky Locker in the Touchpal settings.
I have disabled Daily Summary in the Touchpal settings.
The permission "draw over other apps" is disabled for Touchpal. (Do I need to disable it for another app as well?) (This permission is in a separate place from the other permissions)

I am using a Huawei Honor 8 running stock EMUI 4.1. (I haven't updated it yet)

The only permissions Touchpal has are:

- Contacts
- Storage
- Telephone

**How can the Touchpal application show this circle on my home screen with the "draw over other apps" permission disabled?** I thought this permission was for exactly this purpose. And of course **how do I disable it?**

The question is relevant, the answer is not: [Why do some apps not have to ask for the "Draw over other apps" permission?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155069/why-do-some-apps-not-have-to-ask-for-the-draw-over-other-apps-permission)

Comment: Just now, I have tried to enable Lucky Locker in the Touchpal settings, closing the touchpal settings app, disable Lucky Locker and close the Touchpal settings app again. Not sure if it works now. Only time will tell I guess.

Comment: Just as an update: The WIN circle still appears after enabling and disabling Lucky Locker.